# Removing entire html tags in datatables row grouping

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, datatable, datatables

I have this html output from using [datatable](https://datatables.net/extensions/rowgroup/examples/initialisation/startAndEndRender.html) row grouping that take data from my table and unfortunately my table cell is like this:

```
15.000 <i class="fa fa-caret-square-o-down fa-fw text-red" 
          data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" 
          title="decrease 10.000 "></i>
```

and I want to get the `15000` as output only. How to do that with `preg_replace`?

I have tried `/[^\d]/g` but there result is `1500010000` so it remove all tags and combine numbers.

I also tried this `/<i>(.*?)<\/i>/` which is also not working. How can I remove it only with JavaScript?

so here is my rowgroup code

```
rowGroup:{
            endRender:function(rows,group){
                var nomor = [];
                for (i = 9; i < 31; i++){
                    nomor.push(i);
                }
                return $('<tr/>')
                    .append( '<td></td>' )
                    .append( '<td colspan="5" class="tdtotal text-right">TOTAL '+group+'</td>' )
                    .append( $.map(nomor, function(value,key){
                        var ttl=rows
                            .data()
                            .pluck(value)
                            .reduce(function(a,b){ 
                                return a + b.replace(/[^\d]/g,'')*1;
                            },0);   
                        return $( '<td class="bg-aqua disabled color-palette text-right" >'+$.fn.dataTable.render.number('.', ',', 0,).display( Math.abs(ttl) )+'</td>');
                    }))
                    .append( '<td colspan="2" class="bg-aqua disabled color-palette ">&nbsp;</td>' );
            },
            dataSrc: '0'
        }
```

Comment: how to do that in javascript or jquery?

Comment: At least the function preg_replace does not exists in Javascript ;-)

Comment: From where the output come?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not much clear about you question. But you can take the output like below

```js
var string = '15.000 <i class="fa fa-caret-square-o-down fa-fw text-red" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="decrease 10.000 "></i>';

$('button').click(function(){
alert(string.split(' ')[0]);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
```

Comment: i also tried you way but it give me the first number before "." so if 5.349 it will be just return 5

Answer (score 0):

try the regex

```
/^(\d+).(\d+)(.*\n*)*/g
```

and replace with (1st group)(2nd group)

check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/7duHbq/1)

Answer (score 0):

With purpose to get `15.000` from beginning of your output try this:

```
/^[\d]+.[\d]+(?=\s+\<i)/g
```

[here](https://regex101.com/r/EeD75Y/2) how it works.

Comment: i also tried you way but it give me Nan value... any idea why?